# Getting average votes and number of voters

Tags: woocommerce

I want to calculate the average total ratings given to a seller's products on WooCommerce when visiting the author's page, as well as the number of people who rated them. I have written this code but it is not working properly:

```
function get_vendor_ratings($vendor_id) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'author' => $vendor_id,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_wc_average_rating',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    $total_rating = 0;
    $rating_count = 0;

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
            $rating = $product->get_average_rating();

            if ($rating > 0) {
                $total_rating += $rating;
                $rating_count++;
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    if ($rating_count > 0) {
        $average_rating = round($total_rating / $rating_count, 2);
    } else {
        $average_rating = 0;
    }

    return array(
        'average_rating' => $average_rating,
        'rating_count' => $rating_count
    );
}
```

Thanks for your help